# pre-release Collections.Immutable

Tags: .net, f#, immutability

Has anyone succeeded in opening the pre-release `System.Collections.Immutable` from NuGet in F#?

I'm getting this error:

> The type 'IEnumerable`1' is required here and is unavailable. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Even though my project is .NET 4.5

Tried explicitly opening System.Runtime and that did not work either. I am referencing `.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.dll`

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is normally defined in mscorlib.dll, so the fact that it's looking for it in System.Runtime.dll tells me this must be some sort of WinRT/Phone assembly.

Comment: It isn't a phone assembly, but it is a 'portable' assembly that targets reference assemblies that are common to phone, Windows Store, and .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known issue that the relevant teams at Microsoft are investigating.  In the meantime, here are the workaround steps:

1. Create an F# Application project that targets .NET Framework 4.5
2. `Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable -pre`
3. Add a reference to "%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll"
4. Add a reference to the System.ComponenModel.Composition.dll assembly from the Framework.

After that, early testing suggests F# works with the immutable collections just fine.

Comment: This answer would be better if it was posted as a comment or, if this really must be an answer, why not add some authoritative links, sources, or just some explanation how this would solve the original problem?

Comment: @bytebuster Seeing as I *wrote* the software being asked about, I think my authority is good. ;-)  Also, literally answering the question would mean the answer is "no", which probably is less helpful than explaining that Microsoft is aware of an looking into the blocking issue.

Comment: @AndrewArnott - While you're making this library work with F#, are there any plans to make a compatibility layer that exposes F#'s existing immutable lists, sets, dictionaries, and so forth as appropriate interface implementations in System.Collections.Immutable? Maybe some modules that would allow us to work with these interfaces in a manner consistent with how we work with the built-in immutable collections?

Comment: @JoelMueller We'd love to see that happen. It's good to hear from F# programmers on what you'd like to see. Given the time of year everybody's OOF, but hopefully early next month we'll have some better answers for this and other F# related questions regarding these immutable collections.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Thanks. Your workaround builds, so I can get started. I plan to publish some benchmarks to this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/pragmatic-functional-programming-research before the new year.

Since this is pre-release software, I consider a workaround an answer.

Comment: Great. I'd love to see a link to your benchmarks when you have them.

Answer (score 0):

You can installed "System.Collections.Immutable" component from NuGet that will resolved your problem.

Have a look to the URL
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/